# Multiple fields in check statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I like to be able to enter the following values into my table: 0,0 ; 0,1 ; 1,0
But i want to disable the following value: 1,1

I have made the following query:

`CREATE TABLE mytab (a CHAR(1), b CHAR(1), CHECK(a != 1 AND b != 1));`

I am able to enter 0,0 but i am unable to enter 1,0. How do i rewrite this logical statement so it does fit my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check constraint should be:

```
check (not (a = 1 and b = 1))
```

or equivalently:

```
check (a <> 1 or b <> 1)
```

(Actually, these are not exactly equivalent in the presence of `NULL` values.  The second is probably want you want if you allow `NULL` values.)

Comment: Perfect. Can you explain why my original check fails?

Comment: @jipje44 . . . It doesn't implement the right logic.  It checks that *both* values are different from "1", rather than just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` in place of `AND`:

```
CHECK(a != 1 OR b != 1))
```